# Instant back and forward in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Few years ago just before/during the period when Opera became adware (which they eventually got rid of after realizing their folly), I remembered going back and forward in the browser history were instant with no page loads. Is such instant back and forward possible in Google Chrome?

If so, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Its enabled by Default in Chrome.
In chrome when you press back button it doesn't load the page but displays a cached version of the page.